# Can't use WiFi on Ubuntu Server 14.04 even though it appears to be connected

Tags: networking, wireless, server, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I've configured the WiFi SSID and key through `/etc/network/interfaces` as shown below:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid MYWIFINAME
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
wpa-psk WIFIKEYGOESHERE
```

I did not use the usual password. I ran it through `wpa_passphrase` to get the proper key.

Even though these settings seem correct, and running `iwconfig` gives me this:

```
wlan0   IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MYWIFINAME"
        Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: AB:CD:EF:12:34:56
        Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
        Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
        Power Management:off
        Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm
        Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
        Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:4   Missed beacon:0

lo      no wireless extensions.

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

... I can not ping any website, as they all return `unknown host site.com` and I can not ping my own router. Running `ping -c 4 10.0.0.1` returns `Network is unreachable`, so what can I do? I don't have any information on the server right now, so I could wipe and reinstall if necessary.

When the server is rebooted, starting it up causes it to stall on `Waiting for networking configuration`, and it gives itself over 60 seconds to finish, but gives up.

Output of `sudo ifup -v wlan0`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12989292/

EDIT: I decided to wipe the server, and I'm going to install Ubuntu Server in a VM in order to make it easier to use the Internet connection. It will be much easier to set up in Windows.

Comment: Does `ifconfig` show that you have an address? Is there another interface that it is trying to send packets through?

Comment: @StephenAngelico When I run `ifconfig` I see `Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AB:CD:EF:12:34:56` and then on 3 more lines different IPv6 address ranges that all end in `/64`. The first is Global, second is Link, and third is also Global.

Comment: I'm not sure offhand what the significance of that is. Is eth0 getting in the way? Could you have not got an address? If you take wlan0 down and bring it up again, does it say `bound to x.x.x.x - renewal in y seconds` or `No DHCPOFFERS received`?

Comment: I don't have `eth0`, just `wlan0` and `lo` because I disabled Ethernet in the BIOS menu, just to make sure it wasn't interfering. When I run `sudo ifdown wlan0` then `sudo ifup wlan0`, the `ifup` command says `Listening on LPF/wlan0/AB:CD:EF:12:34:56` then `Sending on   LPF/wlan0/the same MAC` then `Sending on   Socket/fallback`. After that it just repeats `DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval X (xid=0x8bcc3505)` forever.

Comment: @StephenAngelico After about 3 minutes of repeating `DHCPDISCOVER`... it says `No DHCPOFFERS received.` then `No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.` Does this mean it's not getting an IP address from my router?

Comment: That's right. Check the logs on your server to see if the requests are getting there, otherwise see if the router is playing up.

Comment: @StephenAngelico thanks. Where do I find the log for DHCP? I'm mostly new to Ubuntu, so sorry about that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Returns nothing. What does this mean?

Comment: Is it a PCI or USB adapter?

Comment: @Pilot6 It is a USB adapter. Sorry about that. Should I use a different command?

Comment: It is `lsusb` then.

Comment: @Pilot6 Here is the entry for the device I'm using: `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]`

Comment: @Pilot6 if wlan0 shows up as an interface, I don't see how much difference the actual device model makes. Are you looking for driver issues?

Comment: The kernel driver does not work well for this device. It actually never works.

Comment: Your NIC did not get assigned IP address from DHCP. Does other wifi device working??

Comment: @AizuddinZali All other devices on the network are working fine. It just seems to be this computer.

Comment: @Pheonix Try `dhclient wlan0` and kill any dhclient process first.

Answer (score 0):

Please amend your */etc/network/interfaces* file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid MYWIFINAME
wpa-psk WIFIKEY
```

Where WIFIKEY is the actual key in clear text. Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

Test:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

The -v for verbose in the `ifup` command should produce sufficient output to diagnose why you didn't connect. As it may be lengthy, please post it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: I still get `ping: unknown host www.ubuntu.com` from that. One thing I was curious about is that I don't have an IP address when I run `ifconfig`, even though running `iwconfig` shows my SSID seeming to be configured. It even shows my router's MAC address.

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` can handle a plain text password as well as an encrypted key.

Comment: @StephenAngelico That's good to know, because I'd rather not have to deal with `wpa_passphrase` again.

Comment: @PhoenixLogan It's always a good idea to use wpa_passphrase to encrypt them.

Comment: @StephenAngelico It is a little awkward trying to type the entire key out, but I guess it isn't a big deal if it makes it more secure, instead of storing the plain text. Although for now I just have the key in plaintext.

Comment: @StephenAngelico `/etc/network/interfaces` will only accept an encrypted password in the context of a fully configured wpa_supplicant.conf file. That is not the case here, nor is it required.

Comment: @PhoenixLogan Please see my edit to the answer above.

Comment: @chili555 I uploaded the paste. It seems like DHCP is not working for some reason.

Comment: Your NIC did not get assigned IP address from DHCP. Does other wifi device working??

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a driver for this adapter. Connect to internet with some other adapter and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware
```

If you do not have other adapter then download these files:

https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192cu-dkms_0.2~trusty_all.deb

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb

https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/linux-firmware_1.144%2Bar3012_all.deb

copy them to the `/home/$USER` directory and run

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Are you sure? `iwconfig` shows my wifi network, so I assume the driver is working.

Comment: OK. Then keep complaining.

Comment: Well, the driver is at least "functioning" even if it isn't working. Is there any way to download this package to a flash drive? I don't have another adapter.

Comment: I added that to the answer.

Comment: There are some missing dependencies: `gcc`, `make`, `build-essential`, and `dpkg-dev`. Where can I get these?

Comment: You need to download them too. It looks like the server does not have them installed. You can find and install the packages the same way. Search http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gcc , etc for your distribution and platform and install them the same way.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help. I'll let you know how it goes.